# Search Text Messages

Tags: sms

I would like to search my past text messages.  I often forget which person I was talking to about the different issues and global search is helpful.  Here is a picture of the equivalent functionality on the iPhone.

[image: iOS search text messages]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for this functionality in the default message app. If not ChompSMS is an option. This app seems to provide this function.

[image: ChompSMS search example]

Answer (score 1):

This [SMS Organizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=main.organizer.sms.trailblaze.smsorganizer&hl=en) app has advanced search capabitilies.

It can search for any keyword, in the message content and also in the sender's name.

[image]

While you can search for all the messages in the "All Conversations" view, you can also arrange messages into folders, which can make searching and locating sms-es a lot easier. 

For example, you can create a folder for all messages from a particular contact, so later you have to search in only that folder.